# Database is not ready and resetting does not solve it Heroku

Tags: database, heroku

I am trying to deploy a version of the otree Social Value Orientation measure following a slightly modified version of https://github.com/drfwint/svo. I can run it locally without problems but once I deploy it on Heroku-18 (since I have python 3.7 which is not supported on Heroku-20) I get the following message:

- "Your database is not ready. Try resetting the database (Missing tables for otree.X, auth.Y, svo.Z, and 18 other models)."

I reset my database and it is still not working. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: "I reset my database"—how? It sounds like there are migrations or something that need to be applied.

Comment: Using:    `heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL -a MYAPP`

Comment: That is definitely not what the error message is telling you to do. [`heroku pg:reset`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-pg-reset-database) deletes all your data. The error message suggests you need to run migrations. It looks like that project uses Django? How did you set up your database locally? Did you have to run `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Hi @Chris thank you so much for your help. I am new to this. I ran  `python manage.py migrate` too and got an error:  `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'otree.management' " It is odd because I have a virtual environment on an external libraries on Python 3.8 which has the otree file on the site-packages which includes the management file... Do you know why it is not reading it?

Comment: Did you do this on your local machine or on Heroku, e.g. via `heroku run`? Let's figure out how you got your local machine working first, then we can do the same on Heroku.

Comment: Okay, well, you said your local machine was already working. Had you run that command before? Or did you do something else to set this up initially?